# Convert string of listcomp to listcomp using literal_eval

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert the string of a list comprehension (user input) into an actual list comprehension. I am using literal_eval from AST.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange']
l1 = '[ele for ele in fruits]'
l2 = literal_eval(l1)
print(l2, type(l2))
```

This will work if l1 is a string of a list but not if it is a string of a listcomp. If I use just eval() I get the list after comprehension, ['apple', 'orange']. I was hoping to get [ele for ele in fruits] as a class .

Comment: You can't do this with `literal_eval()`. As the name says, it's only for evaluating *literals*. A list comprehension isn't a literal.

Comment: A "listcomp" is not an object, and not an object literal, so `literal_eval` will not work *by design*. Use `eval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python, and generally speaking languages like it, can be thought of having two modes parsing, and executing. If you're in the execution mode (your source has been parsed), you have to `eval` to get back to the parsing mode. That tells it what it previously thought was a string is special, and that it's code.

You're right to for `eval`, but you just want `eval` not `literal_eval`

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,42]
>>> code = "[x for x in a if x > 2]"
>>> eval(code)
```